# Spring JPA hibernate4 interceptor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, interceptor

What annotation should I be using if I write a class which extends EmptyInterceptor.

Is there an example that somebody can point me. Should I be using Hibernate's EmptyInterceptor or does spring has some other class that I should be using

thanks

Comment: Are you using spring-mvc? If so you can use interceptors in spring-mvc. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

Answer (score 0):

The hibernate document has example on how to use the interceptors at [Chapter 14. Interceptors and events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch14.html) and when it comes to Hibernate there are no interceptors provided I guess.

For using annotations using Spring for Hibernate interceptors, you can have a look at this post - [Use Spring annotations to automatically apply Hibernate Interceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132151/use-spring-annotations-to-automatically-apply-hibernate-interceptor)